# Some Linux Kernel C codes

Tags: c, linux, kernel

```
ifdef _KERNEL__
```

1)does the __ of the **KERNEL** means anything to the compiler?

```
#define namei(pathname) __namei(pathname, LOOKUP_FOLLOW)
```

2) WHAT'S THIS __namei?

```
#define FIBMP __IO(0x00, 1)
```

3) what's this __IO?

```
#define pr_info(fmt, arg..) |
printfk(KERN_INFO fmt, ##arg)
```

4)what's this ##?

Answer (score 2):

1) If you have a

```
#define __ something
```

somewhere, then it means something.
Else, it´s just part of the name `_KERNEL__`

2) That will just replace every `namei(pathname)` with `__namei(pathname, LOOKUP_FOLLOW)`.
Latter is a function call to a function somewhere in the code and parameters.

3) The same. Replaces every `FIBMP` with `__IO(0x00, 1)`,
which is a function or `#define` somewhere else

4) Are there three points after arg? Then it´s an variadic macro. Ie.
replace `pr_info(a)` with `printfk(KERN_INFO a)`
replace `pr_info(a, b)` with `printfk(KERN_INFO a, b)`
replace `pr_info(a, b, c)` with `printfk(KERN_INFO a, b, c)`
and so on. Without the `##`, it would be
replace `pr_info(a)` with `printfk(KERN_INFO a, )`
replace `pr_info(a, b)` with `printfk(KERN_INFO a, b, )`
replace `pr_info(a, b, c)` with `printfk(KERN_INFO a, b, c, )`
The trailing comma is the difference, it would result in compiler errors.
A comma is only there if it is followed by a parameter when using `##`.